# Label expands vertically in a QVBoxLayout

Tags: qt, layout, label

I have inserted a `QLabel` with a small sentence, a `QLineEdit` and a `QPushButton`, in this order, into a `QVBoxLayout`. My main window is 70% of the user's desktop.

My problem is that my label expands to nearly 80% of the parent window's height and the `QLineEdit` and the `QButton\ are squeezed at the bottom.

I figured out a way to solve this: I inserted more labels with no content but this can't be the golden solution. What can I do?

I also tried `QFormLayout` but it does not fit my needs. I like the widgets to be in a vertical order. I tried many ways with `QSizePolicy` but it did not work out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is to add a spacer item. Try using [`addStretch`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qboxlayout.html#addStretch) on your layout after you've added all your widgets to it.

Example:

```
#include <QtGui>

class W: public QWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        W(bool spacer, QWidget *parent = 0)
            : QWidget(parent)
        {
            QLabel *l = new QLabel("Hello!");
            QLineEdit *e = new QLineEdit;
            QPushButton *p = new QPushButton("Go");

            QVBoxLayout *vl = new QVBoxLayout;
            vl->addWidget(l);
            vl->addWidget(e);
            vl->addWidget(p);

            if (spacer)
                vl->addStretch();

            setLayout(vl);

            resize(200, 400);
        }
};
```

Renders:

[image]

(No stretch on the left, stretch on the right.)

Comment: thank you thats exactly what i was looking for :) i will try this ;) but what doas if(spacer) means?

Comment: It's just a parameter in the constructor I put there to be able to show the two easily. (i.e. the window on the left was created with sth like `new W(false);`, the one on the right with `new W(true);`.) It's just for this demo.